# Constructing a Transformer for sklearn Pipeline - Replacing nulls by KNN prediction

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to write a class that replaces the missing values of a DataFrame within one target variable, based on its k nearest neighbors identified with the other variables.
This class will "fit" a KNN on the train set that will later "predict" the missing values for the train and the test set.

**This class must be included in a sklearn.Pipeline**, which means it must contain a fit() and transform() function, that will be called by the pipeline. I cannot find a nice way to write down this class.

What my code does so far:

1. Prepare data for KNN:
   (a) Fill null values using standard techniques
   (b) One Hot Encode categorical variables
2. Fit a KNN on the dataframe where the target variable has been removed
3. Predict the target variable on the rows where target is null

My main problem is that steps 1.a and 1.b create temporary DataFrames that should not be 'refitted' on the test set.

I need your help to put the pieces of my code in the write way.

Here is my code so far:

```
col = 'native-country' #one specific column where nans should be replaced using KNN
n_neighbors = 3

######
#I guess this block should be in a pipeline so that we transform the test set with the same dict as the train set
######
miss = TreatMissingsWithCommons() #this class replaces numerical nans by mean() and categorical nans by most frequent value
miss.fit(data)
data_full = miss.transform(data)

#One Hot Encode categorical variables to pass the data to KNN
ohe = DummyTransformer()
ohe.fit(data_full)
#OHE categorical features on lines where col is not null
data_ohe_full = ohe.transform(data_full[~data[col].isnull()].drop(col, axis=1))

#Fit the classifier on lines where col is null
if data[col].dtype in ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']:
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = n_neighbors)
    knn.fit(data_ohe_full, data[col][~data[col].isnull()])
else:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = n_neighbors)
    knn.fit(data_ohe_full, data[col][~data[col].isnull()])

#OHE on lines where col is null, and make the prediction
ohe_nulls = ohe.transform(data_full[data[col].isnull()].drop(col,axis=1))
knn.predict(ohe_nulls)
```

And here is some help for reproduction:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'age': {0: 39,
  4: 28,
  10777: 53,
  14430: 21,
  19061: 19,
  19346: 39,
  24046: 39,
  25524: 43,
  30902: 18},
 'education-num': {0: 13,
  4: 13,
  10777: 9,
  14430: 7,
  19061: 8,
  19346: 13,
  24046: 4,
  25524: 10,
  30902: 5},
 'native-country': {0: 'United-States',
  4: 'Cuba',
  10777: np.nan,
  14430: 'United-States',
  19061: 'El-Salvador',
  19346: np.nan,
  24046: 'Dominican-Republic',
  25524: 'United-States',
  30902: np.nan},
 'workclass': {0: 'State-gov',
  4: 'Private',
  10777: 'Private',
  14430: np.nan,
  19061: 'Private',
  19346: 'Private',
  24046: 'Private',
  25524: np.nan,
  30902: 'Private'}})
```

EDIT: After a good night I clarified my ideas and got a solution. It is very dirty so I would love some feedback on the good practices that I am missing.

```
class KnnImputer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, target, n_neighbors = 5):
        self.col = target
        self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors

    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        #this class replaces numerical nans by mean() and categorical nans by most frequent value
        miss = TreatMissingsWithCommons() 
        miss.fit(X)
        self.X_full = miss.transform(X)

        #One Hot Encode categorical variables to pass the data to KNN
        self.ohe = DummyTransformer()
        self.ohe.fit(data_full)
        #Create a Dataframe that does not contain any nulls, categ variables are OHE, with all each rows 
        X_ohe_full = self.ohe.transform(self.X_full[~X[self.col].isnull()].drop(self.col, axis=1))

        #Fit the classifier on lines where col is null
        if X[self.col].dtype in ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']:
            self.knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = self.n_neighbors)
            self.knn.fit(X_ohe_full, X[self.col][~X[self.col].isnull()])
        else:
            self.knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = self.n_neighbors)
            self.knn.fit(X_ohe_full, X[self.col][~X[self.col].isnull()])

        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

        #OHE on lines where col is null, and make the prediction
        ohe_nulls = self.ohe.transform(self.X_full[X[self.col].isnull()].drop(self.col,axis=1))

        #Get prediction for nulls in target
        preds = self.knn.predict(ohe_nulls)

        ## Concatenate non nulls with nulls + target preds
        #Nulls + target preds
        X_nulls = X[X[self.col].isnull()].drop(self.col,axis=1)
        X_nulls[self.col] = preds

        X_imputed = pd.concat([X[~X[self.col].isnull()], X_nulls], ignore_index=True)

        return X_imputed#should return the dataframe with a full target
```